# Symfony 3.1 Plain html forms Erros

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am using symfony 3.1 with regular html forms to make it easier to do front-end styling. I am continuously getting the following two errors. the first is;

> The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.

and the second is

> This form should not contain extra fields.

The first is because I don't know how to correctly use the csrf token with plain html forms. My form looks like this:

FormType Class:

```
class TypeFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('isActive', CheckboxType::class)
            ->add('descriptor');

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Type',
            'csrf_protection' => true,
            //'allow_extra_fields' => true
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_bundle_type_form_type';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        // removes the need for the form[$name] requirement for form inputs
        return '';
    }
}
```

html form:

```
<form method="post">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label for="descriptor">Descriptor</label>
        <select class="form-control c-select" id="descriptor" name="descriptor">
            <option value="Award">Award</option>
            <option value="Donation">Donation</option>
            <option value="Event">Event</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="checkbox">
        <label class="" for="isActive">
        <input type="checkbox" id="isActive" name="isActive" checked>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Active</label>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token("app_bundle_type_form_type") }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary-outline pull-right">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/types/new", name="admin_types_new")
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {

        $form = $this->createForm(TypeFormType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            dump($form->getData());die;
        }

        return $this->render('admin/type/new.html.twig');
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested in my fix:

```
<input type="hidden" name="{{ form._token.vars.full_name }}" value="{{ form._token.vars.value }}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is better (and working) approach to form rendering in Symfony:

In your controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/admin/types/new", name="admin_types_new")
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(TypeFormType::class);

    // ...

    return $this->render('admin/type/new.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

In your template:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('admin_types_new'), 'method':    'POST'}) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}

<input type="submit" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Please try this because it is usually a better approach: you don't have to care whether your html which you put by hand is correct and all ids and attributes are present or if csrf is generated properly. All is done by Symfony in this case, you just need to modify underlying FormType class and twig template to shape fields of your form.

More on the topic:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: thank you for your answer this is a very valid approach. However i wanted to be able to reuse the html in other place where Symfony is not generating the mark up. Like an Angular 2 single page app. So i needed the back end forms to work with a plain html form. My fix is below if your interested.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need name your token field as '`_token`'